# Invoke step function from particular step through Lambda Function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Following is the step function which triggers different lambda functions in every step. The step function starts from the 'first_step'.

```
{
"Comment": "Step function",
"StartAt": "first_step",
"States": {
"first_step": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function1",
   "Next": "second_step"
 },
"second_step": {
    "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function2",
   "Next": "third_step"
 },
 "third_step": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function3",
  "End" : true
 }
}
}
```

Now, I want to invoke the step function from a particular step (second_step) through Lambda Function.
That is, as soon as i trigger another Lambda Function (lambda_function4) , the step function should start the execution from the second_step (skipping the first_step) and continue till the end.

Also, I am using Python for creating Lambda Functions.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to add a Choice step at the start of your function to determine what lambda to goto next and pass in a parameter to differentiate. As you cant call a step functions with the option of which step to specifically start at

So it would look like:

```
{
"Comment": "Step function",
"StartAt": "flowDirector",
"States": {
    "flowDirector": {
    "Type" : "Choice",
    "Choices": [
      {
        "Variable": "$.customVarName",
        "StringEquals": "Cancel",
        "Next": "first_step"
      },
      {
        "Variable": "$.customVarName",
        "StringEquals": "CameFromFunction4",
        "Next": "second_step"
      }
    ],
    "Default": "first_step"
    },
"first_step": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function1",
   "Next": "second_step"
 },
"second_step": {
    "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function2",
   "Next": "third_step"
 },
 "third_step": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "lambda_function3",
  "End" : true
 }
}
}
```

And then update your python code to send in an extra parameter into the step function so it can calculate where to start.

```
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn='string',
    name='string',
    input='"{\"customVarName\" : \"CameFromFunction4\"}"'
)
```

From: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.start_execution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035450/invalid-type-for-parameter-input-step-function-start-execution Can you please take a look here?